# play-framework 2 how to escape colon in routes

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

in my play2 routes file, I am trying to use a colon as a literal:

```
GET     /:search                       controllers.SearchController.index()
```

but play complains, that a parameter is missing. How do I escape the colon (I tried backslashing it)?

thanks

Comment: What happens if you encode the path, i.e. `/%3Asearch` instead of `/:search`?

Comment: GET /:search -> action not found

Comment: GET /%3A:search -> works fine, but the browser does not escape the colon at all. I checked the request for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminator_3:_Rise_of_the_Machines this also does not encode the colon as %3A

Comment: ":" is a valid in the path of the URL, no need to escape (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must introduce a dummy regex parameter, as such:

```
GET     /$colon<\:>search           controllers.SearchController.index(colon)
```

You must then also redefine your controller method:

```
public static Result index(String colon) {
 ....
```

The parser is built in such a way that path expressions cannot be escaped, save for this method.