# URL Parameter and routing configuration

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I stumble upon a little detail and just want to be sure I don't miss something obvious.

If I define a route like this:

```
GET    /Program                     controllers.MyProgram.method(program ?= null)
```

The parameter passed via

```
http://localhost:9000/Program?program=MyProgram
```

is *MyProgram*

However, I would rather define a route like this:

```
GET    /Program:program             controllers.MyProgram.method(program)
```

But then the parameter passed via

```
localhost:9000/Program:MyProgram
```

is *:MyProgram*.

How can I get rid of the *:* in front of the parameter?

Of course, I could delete it by hand with Java/Scala but that feels like I am doing something wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to add a regex for the colon:

```
GET /Program$colon<\:>:program       controllers.MyProgram.method(colon, program)
```

The downside is that you have a redundant parameter coming in to your `Action`.

See: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513671/play-framework-2-how-to-escape-colon-in-routes)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to separate your path with param by `/` in your routes E.G: `/Program/:program` By this way, you can avoid colon as prefix in your param received in your `Action` method.